# One object (java bean) as data source on iReport (JasperReports)

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm new in iReport and I have to create a PDF report.

With a JavaBean DataSource you wrap an array (or collection) of JavaBeans but I only need to pass an object (only one instance of a JavaBean). I mean, I have to show in my report the properties of a java bean.

How can I do this? I'm a little bit confused, I have to pass an array with only one item?

Comment: You can find the samples [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/datasource/index.html#javabeandatasources)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can pass your bean to the report using a **JRBeanArrayDataSource** or **JRBeanCollectionDataSource** or you can use the parameters Map.

```
JasperPrint reportPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(
        this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/report.jasper"),
            new HashMap<String,Object>(), 
                 new JRBeanArrayDataSource(new YourBean[]{yourBean}));
```

or

```
Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<String,Object>();
params.put("yourBean", yourBean);

JasperPrint reportPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(
        this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/report.jasper"),
                params, new JREmptyDataSource());
```

Comment: how am i gonna access the specific property of bean after that? yourbean would be a parameter i understand. but lets say it has documentTypes as int[] and i want to show that in report. i am not bale to get that in report through field/parameter?

Comment: @manocha_ak You can call `$P{yourBean}.getDocumentTypes()` or `$P{yourBean}.getDocumentTypes()[0]` in your report. `yourBean` parameter needs to have as parameter class `YourBean` in `iReport`.

Comment: Yes I got it (was thinking of updating the comment). many thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the pre-defined Jasper Reports classes, then yes. The default implementations of [`JRAbstractBeanDataSource`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRAbstractBeanDataSource.html) are limited to dealing with arrays or collections. So you could just create a one element array or one element collection.

The alternative would be to implement your own version of `JRAbstractBeanDataSource` that stubs out the `next()` and `moveFirst()` methods, but that does seem like a silly amount of work to do when there's a straight-forward way to get the required behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have only one bean, you can still use the collection data source. In this case, the collection will have only 1 object. If you create the report design with correct grouping, this report can later be used to show multiple classes with their respective properties.