# jasper report pdf with null values

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I create a jasper report with the following code

```
JasperPrint print = null;
    Map<String, Object> datosReporte = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    JasperReport reporteJasper = crearReporteJasper();
    String rutaPDF = "C:\\AAPG\\algo.pdf";

    try {

        for (int i =0; i< lista.size(); i++) {

            Fin700PDFVO r = (Fin700PDFVO)lista.get(i);

                    datosReporte.put("PROVEEDOR", r.getProveedor());
                    datosReporte.put("RUT", Integer.toString(r.getRut()));
                    datosReporte.put("TIPO", r.getTipo());
                    datosReporte.put("CANTREGISTROS", Integer.toString(r.getCantRegistros()));
                    datosReporte.put("SUMTOTUF", Integer.toString(r.getSumTotUF()));
                    datosReporte.put("SUMTOTPESOS", Integer.toString(r.getSumTotPesos()));


        }
            print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporteJasper, datosReporte, new JREmptyDataSource());
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print, rutaPDF);
```

and

```
private JasperReport crearReporteJasper() {
    JasperReport report = null;
    String sourceFileName = "ReporteFin700";
    InputStream is = null;

    try {
        is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/" + sourceFileName + ".jrxml");
        report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(is);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error al compilar plantilla: " + sourceFileName, e);
        throw new ServiceException("Error al compilar plantilla: " + sourceFileName);
    }
    return report;
```

but when a tried to ran this code I get a pdf just with de column header and the values null.

Comment: `print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporteJasper, datosReporte, new JREmptyDataSource())` - You are passed empty datasource. This is reason of getting empty report

Comment: ok, but which datasources I need to use for this case?

Comment: `which datasources I need to use for this case?` - What case?

Comment: when I use Map<String, Object> as data to create a report , zorry for my english.

Comment: Duplicates: [One object (java bean) as data source on iReport (JasperReports)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9038887/876298).  
You should post the jrxml

Comment: Possible duplicate of [One object (java bean) as data source on iReport (JasperReports)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038887/one-object-java-bean-as-data-source-on-ireport-jasperreports)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it change the JREmptyDataSource as Alex K mentioned, changed this:

```
print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporteJasper, datosReporte, new JREmptyDataSource());
```

for this

```
print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporteJasper, datosReporte, new JRMapArrayDataSource(new Object[] { datosReporte }));
```